# display image when clicked on the item in listview

Tags: android, android-intent

i am using listview... i try open the image when itemclicked on the list and is diaply in another activity...but its not working... help me if freinds you know... thanks....

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);


// Find the ListView resource. 
mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> mainListView, View view, int pos,
            long id) {

        //Object obj = getFilesDir().getPath();
        //String value= obj.toString();

        Intent intent= new         Intent(SimpleListViewActivity.this,Nextclass.class);
        final String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(root + "/mnt/sdcard/dcim/100andro/koala_copy.jpg"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private ArrayAdapter<String> getListAdapter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null; 
    }
```

my main.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/mainListView">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to see `NextClass`'s code as well, since that's what is receiving that Intent you're launching. It should be a subclass of `Activity`. Then in its `onCreate` or `onResume` you call `getIntent()`, check if the intent has the extras/data you need, and load the image into an `ImageView` or something else.